# Can anyone find out why when I run this code for a GPS and BME680 sensor I have no errors but nothing happens

Tags: arduino-mega, adafruit, gps

Here is the code

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Adafruit_Sensor.h>
#include "Adafruit_BME680.h"
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

#define BME_SCK 13
#define BME_MISO 12
#define BME_MOSI 11
#define BME_CS 10

#define SEALEVELPRESSURE_HPA (1013.25)

Adafruit_BME680 bme; // I2C
//Adafruit_BME680 bme(BME_CS); // hardware SPI
//Adafruit_BME680 bme(BME_CS, BME_MOSI, BME_MISO,  BME_SCK);

SoftwareSerial gpsSerial(5, 11); // RX, TX (TX not used)
const int sentenceSize = 80;
char sentence[sentenceSize];


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial);
  Serial.println(F("BME680 test"));
  gpsSerial.begin(9600);

  if (!bme.begin()) {
    Serial.println("Could not find a valid BME680 sensor, check wiring!");
    while (1);
  }

  // Set up oversampling and filter initialization
  bme.setTemperatureOversampling(BME680_OS_8X);
  bme.setHumidityOversampling(BME680_OS_2X);
  bme.setPressureOversampling(BME680_OS_4X);
  bme.setIIRFilterSize(BME680_FILTER_SIZE_3);
  bme.setGasHeater(320, 150); // 320*C for 150 ms
}

void loop() {


 static int i = 0;
  if (gpsSerial.available())
  {
    char ch = gpsSerial.read();
    if (ch != '\n' && i < sentenceSize)
    {
      sentence[i] = ch;
      i++;
    }
    else
    {
     sentence[i] = '\0';
     i = 0;
     displayGPS();
    }
  }
}

 

void displayGPS()
{
  char field[20];
  getField(field, 0);
  if (strcmp(field, "$GPRMC") == 0)
  {
    Serial.print("Lat: ");
    getField(field, 3);  // number
    Serial.print(field);
    getField(field, 4); // N/S
    Serial.print(field);
    
    Serial.print(" Long: ");
    getField(field, 5);  // number
    Serial.print(field);
    getField(field, 6);  // E/W
    Serial.println(field);
  }
}

 

void getField(char* buffer, int index)
{
  int sentencePos = 0;
  int fieldPos = 0;
  int commaCount = 0;
  while (sentencePos < sentenceSize)
  {
    if (sentence[sentencePos] == ',')
    {
      commaCount ++;
      sentencePos ++;
    }
    if (commaCount == index)
    {
      buffer[fieldPos] = sentence[sentencePos];
      fieldPos ++;
    }
    sentencePos ++;
  }
  buffer[fieldPos] = '\0';

  
  if (! bme.performReading()) {
    Serial.println("Failed to perform reading :(");
    return;
  }
  Serial.print("Temperature = ");
  Serial.print(bme.temperature);
  Serial.println(" *C");

  Serial.print("Pressure = ");
  Serial.print(bme.pressure / 100.0);
  Serial.println(" hPa");

  Serial.print("Humidity = ");
  Serial.print(bme.humidity);
  Serial.println(" %");

  Serial.print("Gas = ");
  Serial.print(bme.gas_resistance / 1000.0);
  Serial.println(" KOhms");

  Serial.print("Approx. Altitude = ");
  Serial.print(bme.readAltitude(SEALEVELPRESSURE_HPA));
  Serial.println(" m");

  Serial.println();
  delay(2000);
}
```

Comment: What exactly does "nothing happens" mean? You have print statements in setup. Are these showing up in your Serial Monitor?

Comment: All that will show up on the serial monitor is "BME680 test" Then it will just do nothing.

Comment: put in more serial.print statements ... figure out where it stops

Comment: You have the BME pins defined for an SPI connection, but your created an instance for I2C connection with `Adafruit_BME680 bme;`, so how exactly you wire your BME sensor with the Arduino?